# Given two JSON schemas, one a from schema and one a to schema, I need a way to ensure that the from schema satisfies the to schema

Tags: javascript, json, schema, jsonschema

For example, the following would be valid because the *to schema* specifies an array of items, each of which will have an age and a title field, and the *from schema* specifies that same (along with additional fields) which are allowed by the `additionalProperties` flag.

From Schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    type: 'array',
    items: {
      type: 'object',
      required: ['imageUrl', 'title', 'age'],
      properties: {
         color: {
           type: 'string'
         }
         imageUrl: {
           type: 'string',
         },
         title: {
           type: 'string'
         },
         age: {
           type: 'number'
         }
      }
    }
}
```

To Schema

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    type: 'array',
    items: {
      type: 'object',
      additionalProperties: true,
      required: ['age', 'title'],
      properties: {
         title: {
           type: 'string'
         },
         age: {
           type: 'number'
         }
      }
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to perform such a comparison using JavaScript?

Note: I'm not looking for a way to validate a JSON file. I need a way to check the file that will be validated succesfully by the *from schema* will also satisfy the *to schema*.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-subset

Comment: Can `items` be nested?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks. I was thinking there would be more standardised way of doing this, but I guess that would get me to the same place.

Comment: @JohanP Unfortunately they can be anything that is a valid JSON schema.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That library is problematic as it requires all array items to have the same keys for it to be deemed a subset, so `['a','c'] ` isn't seen as a subset of '['a','b', 'c']`.